Why does regex get tripped up on this
Have the below set up to parse text to individual transactions:
transactions = rx.findall(r"(\([A-Z][\s\S]*?\$.*\$[,\d]+)", text)

For the below sample text, I'd expect to return 6 transactions (one for each ticker represented--denoted initially by a "([A-Z])" pattern.
text string
SP Alphabet Inc. - Class A Common
Stock (GOOGL) [ST]S (partial) 02/01/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.
SP Amazon.com, Inc. - Common Stock
(AMZN) [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $15,001 -
$50,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.
SP Koninklijke Philips N.V. NY Registry
Shares (PHG) [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.
SP Pfizer, Inc. Common Stock (PFE) [ST] P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.
SP QUALCOMM Incorporated -
Common Stock (QCOM) [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.
SP Unilever PLC Common Stock (UL)
[ST]S 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
D: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.

unformatted text

"SP Alphabet Inc. - Class A Common\nStock (GOOGL)  [ST]S (partial) 02/01/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\nSP Amazon.com, Inc. - Common Stock\n(AMZN)  [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $15,001 -\n$50,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\nSP Koninklijke Philips N.V. NY Registry\nShares (PHG)  [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\nSP Pfizer, Inc. Common Stock (PFE)  [ST] P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\nSP QUALCOMM Incorporated -\nCommon Stock (QCOM)  [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\nSP Unilever PLC Common Stock (UL)\n[ST]S 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000\nF\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: New\nD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00: Part of my spouse's retirement portfolio.\n"

This pattern:
 transactions = rx.findall(r"(\([A-Z][\s\S]*?\$.*\$[,\d]+)", text)

Only returns 5 transacations--it returns the AMZN and PHG transactions together as one record.
Why is it getting tripped up for security (PHG) here?

The * in \$.*\$ is greedy, so it will match everything between the first and last $. Use .*? to make it non-greedy.

Also to mention your dot in .* (besides it's greedy, which Barmar mentioned) also "tripps" as you say at the newline, doesn't it. So you could just use re.DOTALL e.g. (?s)\([A-Z].*?\$.*?\$[,\d]+ but 4th bird idea is certainly more efficient if you can use that.
